# Gradle tasks missing after bumping gradle version

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I was previously using Gradle 2.3 and the Gradle Android plugin 1.3.1.

After upgrading to 4.0.1 and 2.3.0 respectively, my build fails with the following message:

`Task with name 'packageReleaseJar' not found in project`

Is there a compatibility problem between these versions of Gradle? I believe this is not a custom defined task.

Comment: Share your build.gradle, please. The problem can be at build.gradle as well as Gradle Android plugin version, that does not work with 4+ only with 2+